# replace comma to dot in perl array

Tags: arrays, perl, replace

Does anyone know how to replace commas with dots in an array in perl?

```
INPUT:

my @array = qw(6,2 5,2 4,2 3,2 2,2 1,2);

foreach (@array) {
print $_."\n";
}

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

6.2
5.2
4.2
3.2
2.2
1.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

```
s/,/./g for @array;
```

But since there is nothing regex-y about the LHS of the substitution, [`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) is more purpose-built for the task:

```
tr/,/./ for @array;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [transliteration](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html)

```
foreach (@array) {
  tr/,/./;
  print $_, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
no warnings 'qw'
```

to be able to do this at all without Perl complaining. (You *do* have warnings enabled I hope?)

This will do what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

no warnings 'qw';

my @array = map tr/,/./r, qw(6,2 5,2 4,2 3,2 2,2 1,2);

say for @array;
```

**output**

```
6.2
5.2
4.2
3.2
2.2
1.2
```

---

**Update**

If you have `@array` defined already and need to modify it, then you can write just

```
tr/,/./ for @array
```

Comment: golf: `say tr/,/./r for@array;`

Comment: @ikegami : `y/,/./,say for@array;`